# GLFW linking, undefined reference to init

Tags: linux, opengl, glfw

So i am trying to compile a simple GLFW window app, and i ran into a linker problem.

```
gcc -o bin/mtx_gui `pkg-config --libs glfw3 glew` src/main.c
```

i use this command to compile single main. pkg-config expands into `-L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL` which should compile everything. i checked all libs are where they suposed to be. no idea why it is not linking it

```
main.c:(.text.startup+0x2): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
```

Comment: Try moving the libs spec to the end of the command: gcc -o bin/mtx_gui src/main.c \`pkg-config --libs glfw3 glew\` .

Comment: attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a succeeded well i just ran it in verbose mode to see if it actually links it. looks like it found the lib, but yeah u are right... changing the order helped....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as pointed by G.M in the comment, main.c goes before all libs. second and the most important.

```
-lglfw3 -lrt -lm -ldl -lpthread -lGL
```

Libpthread must be also linked, and if you plan on using opengl link Libgl as shown above.